# Binding two UserControls to the same DataContext, or ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, user-controls, datacontext

I am working on a `UserControl`, which is composed of a `Chart` panel and another area which manipulates some of the chart data i.e. the chart controls (change color of graph, enable or disable stuff on the chart, etc.).

I use a `ViewModel` to manage the chart and its data, but was thinking maybe it would be nice to make a separate usercontrol out of the chart control area to keep my xaml from getting to big and to separate out the components.

If I do this though, since the controls would need to manipulate the data from the `Chart` `ViewModel`, how should I approach it?  Can I bind the `DataContext` of the `Chart` controls to the `DataContext` of the `Chart`, so I just have one `ViewModel`?  Should I give my chart control its own viewmodel and then have the chart panel and chart controls viewmodels talk somehow?

Or just forget about a separate usercontrol and stuff everything into one big viewmodel/xaml control?

What would people recommend in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You absolutely can have your two `UserControl`s bind to the same `ViewModel`. You can either bind the `DataContext` of each to the same object instance, or I suppose you could have the `DataContext` of one control bound to the `DataContext` of the other and have it bound to your `ViewModel`.

If you're starting with a working implementation of your view and your viewmodel, and you feel like the XAML is getting unwieldy, I would agree that you should separate the XAML into multiple views. There's no reason that means you need to separate your `ViewModel` implementation until you feel that it is becoming incoherent, or just too big. Separating it now would just add complexity as you suggested that they would need to communicate anyway.

You might consider starting by simply creating a `UserControl` out of the chart controls area and embed that control inside your existing control. Then you don't have to modify any screens that use your chart control.

Comment: Cool, this will definitely simplify things for me.  Can you provide a small example or link that shows me how to bind the DataContext of each to the same object instance, or bind the DataContext of one control to datacontext of the other?  Either should work, but I havent found the syntax.  Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out, seems to work okay.
In the child UserControl:
DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SpectraView}}}"

Comment: Be careful about relative source data binding. It can be very costly at runtime! Why not bind directly to the other element by it's name?

Comment: I would like to announce that I am an idiot.  Thank you.  There is no need to bind the DataContext, as if I only create one viewmodel for the whole thing, all children have access to the properties needed.