# Unable to bind dependency property of usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have main UI in which I have called the UserControl1(Charting control).
Charting control have following dependency properties:

- ChartTitle
- ChartDataDetails

In UserControl1 I have called another UserControl2(MultiCharting Control).
Which has some dependency properties like

- MultichartInputData etc.

My problem is when I launch main UI I am unable to bind DataStoreDetail property to DP (ChartDataDetail) of UserControl1.
DataStoreDetail property defined in SetPointModel.cs, which is referred in SetPointVM which is ViewModel for main UI.

**MainUI.xaml:**

```
<Charting:ChartControl x:Uid="Charting:ChartControl_1"
    ChartDataDetails="{Binding Path=Model.DataStoreDetails, Mode=TwoWay,
    diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
```

**UserControl1:**

```
<multicharting:MultiChartControl x:Uid="multicharting:MultiChartControl_1"
    x:Name="MultiChart" MultiChartInputDetails="{Binding MultiChartsInputDetails,
    Mode=TwoWay, "/>
```

Binding between UserControl1 and UserControl2 is working fine, problem in binding between MainUI and UserControl1.

**DP in UserControl1:**

```
public DataDetails ChartDataDetails
{
    get { return (DataDetails)GetValue(ChartDataDetailsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ChartDataDetailsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ChartDataDetailsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ChartDataDetails",
    typeof(DataDetails), typeof(ChartControl),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(ChartDataDetailsChanged)));
```

Comment: Hard to grasp, but did you set the `this.DataContext = `?

Comment: Check the **Output Window** for clues. This is probably a problem with the DataContext of the UserControl. I hope you haven't done `this.DataContext = this;`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the same ViewModel for the UserControls mentioned and set their DataContexts accordingly.

Or

try to change the DataContext on your UserControls :

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
 AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.DataStoreDetails}" ...
```

Comment: I've seen many posts about two ore more UserControls bound to the same ViewModel. One of them would be this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163520/binding-two-usercontrols-to-the-same-datacontext-or-viewmodel . What's the big deal here and why down voting without giving a minimum explanation?